# Fast vectorized way to convert row vector to inptrs for sparse matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

For sparse matrices, we usually pass in column indices (`indices`) and an `indptr` vector that indexes the `indices` vector so that `indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]` are the elements of row `i` in the sparse matrix.

Is there a fast, vectorized, preferably numpy solution to convert a vector of consecutive
row indices into an `indptr` in Python?

For example, if this is my `rows` indices vector: `[0,1,1,2,2,2,3,5]`...

The `indptr` vector would be `[0,1,3,6,7,7,8]` where the 7 repeats because the row vector is missing row 4.

I can do it using a simple loop:

```
for i in range(len(rows)):
    indptr[rows[i]+1] += 1
    indptr=np.cumsum(indptr)
```

But I was wondering if there's a faster, vectorized way to do it?

Comment: in your code, what is `rows` and what is initial values of `indptr`? It is not clear how `[0,1,3,6,7,7,8]` is constructed from `[0,1,1,2,2,2,3,5]`

Comment: @Ehsan rows is the row indices of data, and it's sorted from top to bottom. so if  the matrix looks like [[1, 2], [3, 4]], the data array would be [1, 2, 3, 4], the row indices would be [0, 0, 1, 1], and the column indices should be [0, 1,  0, 1]. The row indices, converted to indptrs, would be [0, 2, 4].

Comment: Please see if the posted answer is what you are looking for. If it is, feel free to accept it. If not, please elaborate on how you construct your array `indptr`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
np.bincount(rows).cumsum()
#[1 3 6 7 7 8]
```

And if there are rows at the bottom of your matrix that might be empty, simply add that as argument to `bincount` (per @CJR's recommendation):

```
np.bincount(rows, minlength=num_rows).cumsum()
#[1 3 6 7 7 8]
```

You probably want to insert a `0` in the front as well. What `bincount` does is counting the number of elements in each bin/row and then `cumsum` adds them up. This way you will include missing bins/rows as well.

The best way to insert a 0 is probably by this:

```
np.bincount(np.array(rows)+1).cumsum()
#[0 1 3 6 7 7 8]
```

or you can directly do it by:

```
np.insert(np.bincount(rows).cumsum(),0,0)
#[0 1 3 6 7 7 8]
```

Comment: Make sure you set `minlength` in bincount to the # rows in the matrix or you'll miss empty rows at the end in your indptr array.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be

```
n = len(rows)
indptr = np.searchsorted(rows, np.arange(-1,n), side='right')
```

Not sure which is faster/ better